# Windows Show Desktop causes WinForms elements to stop updating (2)

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

Is there a simple way to have elements on a form keep updating even after I click on Windows Show Desktop? The following code updates the value in textBox1 until I click on Windows Show Desktop (Windows 10 - click on the bottom right of the screen). I prefer not to use Application.DoEvents()

```
    private async void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (true) {
            Task<int> task = Increment(n);
            var result = await task;
            n = task.Result;
            textBox1.Text = n.ToString();
            textBox1.Refresh();
            Update();
            // await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<int> Increment(int num)
    {
        return ++num;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Timer` for this?

Comment: Regarding the `Increment` method, are you getting a warning about an `async` method lacking an `await` operator? Also what's the purpose of the commented `await Task.Delay(200);` line?

Comment: I don't use a timer because I want to modify the function Increment () to do various work as fast as possible. In the function Increment I didn't use an await because I don't know how to use it (I know it should be there somewhere). If I use the line await Task.Delay(200) the program works, but I don't want to introduce any delays.

Comment: I basically need any sample code that shows the value of n after incrementation in a textbox without using any delays (or Application.DoEvents() )and that keeps working even after pressing Windows Show Desktop.

Comment: I see. A workaround maybe is to stop updating the UI when the Form get minimized? Add a condition in the while loop: `if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) { /* Non-UI routines and */ return; }` See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I hope there is a better way using async programming, without having to resort to checking the windows states.

Comment: use wait functions.

Comment: Hi Zambee, please answer with some code and if it works well, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Show the real work you have to do, not this incrementing integer dummy fill-in. It would be better to seek a way to make the UI event based, rather than tight loop poll based

Comment: *The following code updates the value* - I doubt it does- the only thing that would let the UI thread temporarily escape the infinite loop you've put it into and go back to what it should be doing (drawing the UI) is commented out

Comment: That is very easy to test and I can tell you it does - it is because the Update() function in there.

Comment: Caius, I intend to use the code in a few different programs. To me, it should not make a difference if I am just incrementing an integer or if I download data from the internet or read all files from a folder for further processing. I see it as calling a function that does some operation. Why complicate things further than they need to.

Comment: @Nick_F Downloading from internet is different from incrementing a number in an infinitive loop. The former is an I/O operation which is a good option for async/await Task, but the later is cpu consuming task which is not a good option for Task. In all real scenarios, if you await the Task in an async event handler, it continues working without freezing UI.

Comment: @reza - Thanks for clarification, I will pay attention to that in my code.

Comment: `await` doesn't *prevent* things from happening, it *allows* things to happen by freeing your thread to go do useful things like redrawing the form or dealing with input. At the moment you are just stuck in an infinite loop, and `textBox1.Refresh()` is only redrawing one box. You probably also want a `CancellationToken` to know when to break out the loop

Comment: The code below doesn't work:        private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                textBox1.Text = n++.ToString();
                string sText = await ReadFile();
                Update();
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> ReadFile()
        {
            string sFile = @"D:\Temp1\Test.txt";
            string sText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(sFile);
            return sText;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to offload the CPU-bound work to a `ThreadPool` thread, by using the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method:

```
private async void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        n = await Task.Run(() => Increment(n));
        textBox1.Text = n.ToString();
    }
}
```

This solution assumes that the `Increment` method does not interact with UI components internally in any way. If you do need to interact with the UI, then the above approach is not an option.

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I was looking for :)